# Cannot view tooltip data using chart.js

Tags: django

I have little problem using chart.js . I can see graphs on screen but when i use aggregation method then i cannot see tooltip and please guide me how can i use looping function with graph here is my 
**views.py**

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
        qs  = Add.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('expense'))

        a = qs.values()    
        print(a)

        labels = ["budget", "Pink", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
        default_items = [a, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]  # PROBLEM IS HERE 

data = {
        "newlabels": labels,
        "newdata": default_items,
        }
        return Response(data)
```

**template t**

```
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/' 

var labels = [] 
var defaultData = []; 


    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(i){
            labels =           i.newlabels
            defaultData =      i.newdata        



            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels, // CHANGED 
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'sum',
                    data: defaultData,  // CHANGED
                }]

              }
          })

          },
```

[image: when i hover on bar unable to see integer . You can see sum is NaN]

Comment: You could `print(default_items)` to see exactly what you're passing into your chart, maybe that would help identify the issue. Better, use a debugger, set a breakpoint to inspect your variables and stop using `print()` to debug. Anyway, it's not clear what you mean by "tooltip" and "use looping function". What are you seeing in the graph and what are you missing?

Comment: When i use     default_items = qs.values() below default items it works but for second aggregation same problem .

Comment: again, what does print(default_items) show **in the code you posted here**?

Comment: let me copy paste from console

Comment: {'newlabels': ['budget', 'Pink', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'], 'newdata': [dict_values([11]), 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]}   before

Comment: dict_values([11])   AFTER ....       I want list not dict value converting does not help

Comment: so basically you're passing [[11], 10, 10, 10... ] to chart.js instead of [11, 10, 10, ...]

Comment: you should just pass the aggregated value, which is `qs['expense__sum']`. When you pass `values()` you're building a **list**.

Comment: Ok let me try it

Comment: Post an answer bro its working :) And thanks for helping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Sum` [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) over a queryset that isn't assigned to a custom name will just return a dictionary with the key `<fieldname>__sum`. So you can get the result of the aggregation using `qs['expense__sum']`.